# Select tag ASP.NET Core don't have items

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the code

```
public class DeliveryViewModel
{
    public string City { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; } = new[]
    {
        new City { Id = 0, Name = "город доставки" },
        new City { Id = 0, Name = "Moscow" },
        new City { Id = 0, Name = "Yaric" }
    };
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
<div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.City, new SelectList(Model.Cities, "Id", "Name"))
        <select id="store-theme" name="store-theme" asp-for="City" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Cities,"Id","Name"))"></select>
</div>
```

DropDownListFor woks fine, but select tag make empty list.

It works onli if I make this

```
    <select>
        @foreach (City item in Model.Cities)
        {
            <option value=@item.Id>@item.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
```

How to solve it?

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work correctly. Can you please elaborate on what is not working for you?

Comment: Fail to reproduce the issue based on your code . [Here](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-lewlu_microsoft_com/EQlCPzmWirJGpV2PD1KiuEQBFozdIUMrfIlM0m3LTqpnkA?e=TsJlEM) is my working demo , you could refer to check the difference . Could you  share more details or a demo that can reproduce the issue  , so that we can provide the effective suggestions .

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<select asp-for="City" asp-items="@Model.Cities.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Value = c.Name, Text = c.Id.ToString() }))"></select>
```

Comment: Don't wotk too.